# SWIFT compiles successfully but crashes at simulation

Tags: ios, swift

I copied a module with Storyboard and ViewControllers to another project. In the new project the new Storyboard should appear from a tab bar. However, I am getting the following error:

> Thread 1: "[<UIViewController 0x7fcc0ea5da10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key addBarButton."

A picture is attached to the appropriate connection.

[addBarButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfl6a.jpg)

The addBarButton is connected to the correct ViewController. How should I fix this error?

Comment: It’s connected as an outlet and not as an action, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is connected as an IBOutlet.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson should I change it to action?

Answer (score 1):

`<UIViewController 0x7fcc0ea5da10>` suggests that the view controller that has been created is not of the class you expect, if you've copied a module from another project you may have to make sure that module of the view controller is correctly defined in the storyboard identity inspector. The drop down will show you the valid options.